# How to sum each number in array position AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two lists of arrays with random numbers (like two lines) and I want to sum each position to pass to another sum, to choose a number I need to use keyboard numbers but the problem is I have the `ng-model` using all the scopes and the same number not for the each number to sum.

[JS Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/yfkjmren/5/)

Comment: instead of using ng-model, use ng-click and write a function that does the sum with the values previously stored.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://jsfiddle.net/yfkjmren/3/

Comment: is like you are doing but sum each number like this https://jsfiddle.net/yfkjmren/5/ using your code more or less

Comment: now i need to iterate and get the result for each sum but the problem now is on the forEach i can't stop the iteration when the result it's ok don't know how to do that 
updated link https://jsfiddle.net/yfkjmren/6/